# Parent container doesn't grow with height property

Tags: html, css, layout, sass, compass-sass

Stackoverflow community

I know I know, lots of this cases out there, but seriously i try to apply solutions to my case and doesn't fix anything. Seems very very very basic stuff but through this afternoon I can't find the reason of **Why my container doesn't expand?**

I try to modify my 'height property' and anything happen. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/duranmla/9b6a11eba20d04403f99

The final Idea is that My footer has a height of 20% ~ 25% of my page. However as I've already said it is just stuck in that height that comes like for 'default'

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "my container doesn't expand"?

Comment: You have height auto and then height:10% on the child .... That's not the way `height in %` can work

Comment: And include a jsfiddle if possible so we can play with it. =)

Comment: Thanks for your time guys, I've already see the answer.. Sorry again..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not contain the code relevant to the question.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. Sorry for bother but anyway I suppose that someone could be useful the answer, the think is that you need to **stick the element that you to re-size to some side to the screen** by setting top, bottom, left or right to any value. my case just `bottom: 0`